# Finding ideal load factor

Tags: java

I've implemented a hash table data structure in Java, for educational purposes, and now I want to find the ideal load factor that maximizes performance. Right now it is .75 (that is, I double the hash table when the `number_of_entries/number_of_buckets >= .75`. I'm assuming there's no magical algorithm that computes the best load factor - we have to do it through testing. But how would I do such tests? How did the Computer Scientists who researched this do the testing? I was just planning to build a hash table out of various different load factors, and take the average time it took to retrieve an item for each built hash table.

Comment: There's like some probabilistic math you can do to prove what the idea load factor is for your particular implementation, but generally speaking as you've described is how it's done. Remember that you'll have to do thousands of iterations at each table size. And remember that what you're really finding this the point at which the inefficiency of the table starts to outweigh the cost of re-allocating the bins.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any guides for carrying out empirical methods like this?

Comment: Like, are there any standard ways of carrying out testing (i.e., ones in research papers).